# Convert List to a specific JSON format in Play framework using Scala

Tags: json, scala, playframework

I've a List of a type which contains three fields (services, total, improved). When I convert it to JSON using Json.toJson(myList), I get the JSON in the following format:

```
  [
  {
     "services":"S4",
     "total":1,
     "improved":1
  },
  {
     "services":"S1",
     "total":2,
     "improved":1
  },
  {
     "services":"S2",
     "total":3,
     "improved":2
  }
  ]
```

Using JSON library in Play 2.x in Scala, how can I convert myList in the following JSON format?

```
[
 {
   "key" : "total",
   "values" :[
      {
      "services" : "s1",
      "value" : 2
      },
      "services" : "s2",
      "value" : 3
      {
      "services" : "s4",
      "value" : 1
      }
    ]
 }, 
 {
   "key" : "improved",
   "values" :[
      {
      "services" : "s1",
      "value" : 1
      },
      "services" : "s2",
      "value" : 2
      {
      "services" : "s4",
      "value" : 1
      }
    ]
 }
 ]
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are already dealing with OO, I think you could wrap your List into a more specific object and convert it to JSON :

```
case class Foo(services: String, total: Int, improved: Int)

case class B(key: String, value: Int)
case class A(key: String, values: Seq[B] = Seq())

val myOriginalList = Seq(Foo("S4", 1, 1), Foo("S1", 2, 1), Foo("S2", 3, 2))

val transformedList = myOriginalList.foldLeft((A("total"), A("improved")))({ (res, x) =>
    (res._1.copy(values = B(x.services, x.total) +: res._1.values),
    res._2.copy(values = B(x.services, x.improved) +: res._2.values))
}).map({x => List(x._1, x._2)})

Json.toJson(transformedList)
```

One of the problem (or maybe not) using this solution, is that you don't resolve the Foo attributes dynamically.

You could also try yourself around Json Transformers : http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/ScalaJsonTransformers

Answer (score 0):

Here's a Scala newbie's solution (I'm sure it's not elegant): 
I'm using a solution provided here: http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.1/ScalaJson

```
 //some data
 case class PatientAggregateValues(total: Int, improved: Int)
 val scoreMap = Map.empty[String, PatientAggregateValues]
 scoreMap += ("S1" -> PatientAggregateValues(2, 1))
 scoreMap += ("S2" -> PatientAggregateValues(3, 2))
 scoreMap += ("S4" -> PatientAggregateValues(1, 1))

      //main logic
 val totalMap = scoreMap map { case (k,v) => Json.toJson(scala.collection.immutable.Map("service" -> Json.toJson(k), "value" -> Json.toJson(v.total))) } toSeq

 val improvedMap = scoreMap map { case (k,v) => Json.toJson(scala.collection.immutable.Map("service" -> Json.toJson(k), "value" -> Json.toJson(v.improved))) } toSeq

 Json.toJson(scala.collection.immutable.Map("total" -> totalMap, "improved" -> improvedMap))
```

Thanks.